# Verificar si una foto se seteo en el ImageView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, listener

Tengo una app que setea una imagen en un imageView, el imageView tiene un:

```
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: scaleType = "fitCenter
```

Esto para que la imagen no se deforme, posteriormente uso el height de ese ImageView. El problema es que tarda en setearse la imágen mientras que el flujo continua y cuando tomo el height de ese ImageView me llega un 0.
Ya trate de usar varios métodos para obtener el height como tomarlo desde la imagen directamente (desde un bitmap), pero si es necesario que lo tome desde el ImageView

También intente con este método entre otros:

```
imageView.setbackgroundResource(R.id.imagen)
```

Como ultimo recurso puse un handler para darle tiempo de cargar la imagen, pero eso no es correcto, además de que si en un celular mas lento, pasaría el mismo problema.

¿Como puedo verificar si ya se lleno ese Imageview mediante un evento?

Comment: Podrías usar la librería Glide para cargar la imagen y sobreescribir el método onResourceReady para que allí tomes el height

Comment: Uso Glide para cargar la imagen pero sigue el mismo problema, tarda en cargar la imagen y cuando hago un get al height llega vacío.

Comment: Pero usaste el método que te indiqué? Allí deberías de poder obtener el alto, postea el código que tienes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero usar `Glide` y en [onResourceReady()](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/440/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html#onResourceReady-R-java.lang.Object-com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target-com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource-boolean-) puedes asegurar que la imagen fue cargada, ahí puedes obtener sus propiedades.

```
Glide.with(getActivity())
     .load("url de imagen")
     .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
         @Override
         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             //Falló la carga de la imagen.
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

             //* La imagen fue cargada.
             //* Aquí puedes obtener las medidas de la imagen.

             return false;
         }
     })
     .into(imageView);
```